Docker permission denied in Jenkins nodes
I'm working in the CI/CD field, specifically focusing on enhancing the Jenkins instance we use in the project I'm assigned to. Currently, Jenkins is deployed on an AWS EC2 instance (master node) and has 2 slave nodes on other 2 EC2 instances
In the project pipelines, there's a step that uses 'docker' commands. The issue is that after some time, I encounter this error:
permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/auth": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
I've repeatedly accessed the slave nodes and executed the command:
sudo chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock
I also added the jenkins user to sudoers group.
This temporarily resolves the issue, but after a while, which I can't quantify, the error reappears... Any suggestions?
Distro: Ubuntu 22

Is your Jenkins user in the docker group?  That sounds more relevant here.  Changed permissions on the socket will probably be lost when the docker daemon restarts (possibly at other times, too).

yes
$ grep /etc/group -e "docker" docker:x:123:ubuntu,jenkins

Hi @DomenicoScelza , could you provide how your node configured on Jenkins master node whether manually configured or used Amazon EC2 plugin? I can provide an answer to resolve it depends on how it had configured.
You can check "Manage Jenkins" > "Clouds" or "Nodes" console or can be both "Nodes and clouds" up to the version.

I solved the problem simply by restarting the Jenkins process on the master node. Previously, I had added the Jenkins user to the docker group via the CLI, but evidently the master node process did not see this change. Restarting resolved it. Thanks everyone!

If nodes are EC2 instances, then mostly Jenkins configured as following Amazon EC2 plugin, which is mostly used and another case is nodes are manually connected with Jenkins master through Jenkins agent.jar.
I'll describe in the following case of using Amazon EC2 plugin.
1. Check cloud configuration
Once you have installed Amazon EC2 plugin, you can see EC2 node configuration in the following URL or on Jenkins Console:

https://<your-jenkins-ip:port>/manage/cloud/
Console: "Manage Jenkins" > "Clouds" > (Name of cloud type in Amazon EC2).

2. (Option 1) Check docker permission from EC2 AMI

Configured AMI on console.

In the cloud configuration, you can see "AMIs" under "Test Connection" button. Check "AMI ID" by clicking "Check AMI" botton, which will return the AMI name if it exists.

Check Docker group

If the AMI exists, launch an EC2 instance using the AMI and see if docker permission/group was granted/added for the Jenkins user. Since you are adding the permission manually, I would expect that there isn't specific policy that you can't add user to docker group.

Adjust docker group with new AMI

If Jenkins user was not added, you can add the user to docker group using sudo usermod -aG docker ${USER} then generate another AMI from the EC2.
Example of new AMI: ami-0123456

Replace new AMI

After verify on another EC2 with the new AMI of ami-0123456 that Jenkins user was added to docker group, then you can replace the AMI ami-0123456 on the Jenkins console that I mentioned above "1. Configured AMI on console"
If you replace the AMI, make sure all dependencies/configuration are running as you expected for your application.
3. (Option 2) Configure on Init script

In the cloud configuration, you can see "Init script" section under AMIs list. In the section that you can add scripts, which will be executed at EC2 instance init process.

So, add the script sudo usermod -aG docker ${USER} in Init script.
Note that executing script through "Init script" would add user to docker group, but possibly minor issue can cause due to another prior steps are failing or so. In that case, please share any error messages that you have faced.

I solved the problem simply by restarting the Jenkins process on the master node. Previously, I had added the Jenkins user to the docker group via the CLI, but evidently the master node process did not see this change. Restarting resolved it. Thanks everyone!
